# pendrive recovery that damaged while installing linux

Tags: linux, installation, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

I tried to intall linux mint in my hp v165w pendrive.After I partition the device,I clicked on the "next" to install linux.in progress bar after 80% completion the progress stops and cancelled.after that  the pendrive is not showing in any pcs or laptops. I tried to open it in linux os as well in windows os also. but the problem is same.please tell me how to repair the pendrive again.
thank you

Comment: format should do it

Comment: Can you see the partitions on it in a disk manager?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, go to `Disk Management` (Right-click on `My Computer` and then on `Manage`) on any computer whilst the pen drive is plugged in and check if it shows up in there.

If not, go to the `Device Manager` from the `Control Panel`, right-click on the `Disk Drives` node and select `Scan for Hardware Changes` if the device isn't in the listing. After clicking on `Scan for Hardware Changes`, if the USB device appears, it should also appear in `Disk Management`. You should then be able to format the pen driver from `Disk Management`.